# ¿Cómo utilizar vista parcial fuertemente tipada dentro de otra vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Como primera opción estoy intentando crear una vista parcial fuertemente tipada. La misma se renderizaría dentro de dentro de mi `_Layout.cshtml` ya que la idea es que esta vista parcial `_UserInfoPartial.cshtml` se vea en todas las demás vistas.

La segunda sería que desde un vista padre, por ejemplo desde el `home/index`, renderizar la vista antes mencionada.

¿Cómo podría hacer para pasarle otro `model` a la vista hija?

Modelo de la vista parcial:

```
public class DatosUsuario
{
    public short Compania { get; set; }
    public Legajo LegajoUsuario { get; set; }
    public Funcion Funcion { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioNT { get; set; }
}
```

Modelo de la vista padre:

```
public class Visita
{
    public short Compania { get; set; }
    public Local Local { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public DateTime Periodo { get; set; }
    public Legajo LegajoGerente { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaCierre { get; set; }
}
```

Este es mi `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        @Html.Partial("_UserInfoPartial") @*aqui renderizo mi vista parcial*@
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

No se porque opción ir, pero me parece la mas acertada de hacerlo en el `layout` ya que se debería mostrar en todas las vistas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para este caso sería mejor usar un *child action* en lugar de solamente un *partial view*

en un *controller*, digamos *Home*:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Child() {
    var model = new DatosUsuario();
    // ...
    return PartialView("_UserInfoPartial", model);
}
```

(`[ChildActionOnly]` no es obligatorio para invocarlo, solo es para que no sea llamado directamente como una acción normal)

y luego en `_Layout`:

```
@Html.Action("Child", "Home")
```

`@Html.Action` escribe en el layout el resultado de invocar la acción indicada, y ahí puedes especificar la vista y el modelo que deseas usar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Equiso , en cuanto al `controller`, podría ubicar mi _child action_ en cualquiera?

Comment: @Alan Sí puede ser en cualquier `controller`, ya que en `Html.Action` indicas el nombre de la acción y el controllador que quieres usar

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

También puedes poner el modelo de la vista parcial dentro del modelo de la vista padre, y así lo cargas de una vez, todo. Si tienes que cargarlo en todas las vistas créate un modelo base que hereden todos los modelos.

```
@Html.Partial("_DatosUsuario", Model.DatosUsuario)
```

Comment: te dí +1 porque tu sugerencia fue parte de la solución heredar todo de un modelo base. Gracias.