# Cómo retornar una query desde el controlador a una vista que ya tiene datos

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

En una vista, tengo una lista de datos que se cargan a una tabla (tipo grilla) y dentro de ella necesito llamar a un método del controlador para obtener más datos a través de un `url.action`. Ésta es la forma como tengo los datos en la vista:

```
<% For Each item In Model.listadoNoticias%>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.TituloNoticia)%>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.DescripcionNoticia)%>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%: Url.Action("Datos", "Noticias", New With {.id = item.IdNoticia})%>'                                
  </td>  
</tr><% Next%>
```

En el url action al controlador para que me aparezcan datos que provienen de una query. En el controlador:

```
Function Datos (ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
   Using db As New BD_Prueba
   Dim datos = (From t3 In db.FOTO From intermedia In t3.NOTICIA.Where(Function(x) x.IdNoticia = id) Select New With {t3.NombreFoto}).ToList()
    End Using

    Return View(datos)

End Function
```

Me imagino que en vez de ir `ActionResult` debería ser algo como `List(Of String)` y que en vez de `Return View(datos)`, debería ser algo como `Return list(fotos)`. Me gustaría saber cómo sería esta corrección en el controlador, ya  que necesito retornar una lista de datos al url action de la vista.

Y quisiera añadir otra pregunta, si en vez de retornar una lista de string, tuviera que retonar una lista de archivos binarios, ¿cómo sería también en ese caso?

Comment: Mira, por lo que entiendo es que tenes una vista tipada y dentro de esa misma vista necesitas mostrar otros datos diferente al modelo de la vista, esto es así?

Comment: Exactamente. Yo ya muestro datos, pero que añadir mas datos, a través del id que obtengo de los primero datos, de la vista tipeada

Comment: Mira tal ves esta pregunta mia y la respuesa de @equiso [ver aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/968/225) te pueda servir.

Comment: Si bien es sintaxis razor es lo mismo que intentas hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El uso del string.join podria ser como

```
Function Datos (ByVal id As Integer) As String

Using db As New BD_Prueba
    Dim datos As List(Of String) = (From t3 In db.FOTO From intermedia In t3.NOTICIA.Where(Function(x) x.IdNoticia = id) Select New With {t3.NombreFoto}).ToList()

    Return String.Join(", ", datos)
End Using

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es inyectar dentro de la tabla un string o html no deberias usar el `Url.Action()`, sino que deberia ser el `Html.Action()`:

```
<td>
  <%: Html.Action("Datos", "Noticias", New With {.id = item.IdNoticia})%>'                                
</td>
```

De esta forma lo que devuelve el action sera rendericado en ese lugar.

Puedes hacer que el action devuelva un simple string si asi lo necesitas, aunque noto que creas una lista generada desde linq, quizas debas convertirla, si tienes una lista de string podrias usar el `String.Join()` para concatenar los valores separados por un caracter

Una aclaracion, recuerda que existe el `Html.Action()` y el `Html.RenderAction()`

[Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/)

Comment: Exactamente, genero una lista desde linq. Veo que me entendie muy bien la pregunta. Me podrias dar un ejemplo usando String.Join()  porfavor.